# Taylor series expansion for $e^{-x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

could anyone show me the Taylor series expansion for $e^{-x}$.I was trying to find out how

$e^{-i\theta}$=$\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$.

More specifically could you show me how $e^{-i\theta}$=$\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ is obtained from Taylor series.

Comment: Just plug $-x$ into the expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: @Mark McClure:are you saying that the Taylor series expansion becomes $e^{-x}$=$1 - x + \frac{x^2} {2!} - \frac{x^3} {3!} + \frac{x^4} {4!} - \frac{x^5} {5!} +\cdots$

Comment: Yes!  This type of manipulation with power series is very common and has some nice applications.  Also, note that if you differentiate your power series, you end up with exactly -(what you started with), just as if you differentiated $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @Mark McClure:while if you do $\cos x-i\sin x$ what I got is $e^{-x}$=$1 - x - \frac{x^2} {2!} + \frac{x^3} {3!} + \frac{x^4} {4!} - \frac{x^5} {5!} +\cdots$.which isn't which I think we should obtain.

Comment: Well, I was answering your most immediate question, namely: $e^{-x}=?$  If you want the power series for $e^{-i\theta}$, I guess you should plug in $-i\theta$!  If you do so carefully (considering that $i^n$ repeats every fourth integer), then you should find the identity that you want popping out.

Comment: @Mark McClure:can we substitute ${i\theta}$ directly to $e^{-x}$.Because I think that it would form an equation just containing ${i\theta}$.

Comment: Justin - I went ahead and expanded my comments into an answer, though, I noticed that another answer came through with very similar content.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @Mark McClure:that answer really helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ e^{-x} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!} = 1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\dots $$
So plugging in $x=i\theta$ we have that
\begin{align}
e^{-i\theta} &=1-i\theta+\frac{(i\theta)^2}{2!}-\frac{(i\theta)^3}{3!}+\frac{(i\theta)^4}{4!}+\dots\\
&=1-i\theta-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+i\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+\dots
\end{align}
using the fact that $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$ and $i^4=1$, etc.
The [taylor expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are 
$$\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\dots\hspace{10px}\text{and}\hspace{10px}\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\dots $$
So
\begin{align}
e^{-i\theta} &=\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\dots\right)-i\left(\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\dots\right)\\
&=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta.
\end{align}
As a side-note if you already know that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, then it is easy to show that $e^{-i\theta}$ without using taylor-series using the fact that cosine is [even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions) and sine is [odd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions). That is
$$e^{-i\theta} = \cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta, $$
because $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x).$

Comment: that's what I expected.could you show it in terms of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ so I could reach at $\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$
So, taking into account the fact that $i^0=1$, $i^1=i$, $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$, $i^4=1$, etc., we get
\begin{align}
e^{i\theta} &= 
1+(i\theta)+\frac{(i\theta)^2}{2!}+\frac{(i\theta)^3}{3!}+\frac{(i\theta)^4}{4!}+\frac{(i\theta)^5}{5!}+\frac{(i\theta)^6}{6!}+\frac{(i\theta)^7}{7!}+\cdots \\
 &= 1+i\theta+i^2\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+i^3\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+i^4\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+i^5\frac{\theta^5}{5!}+i^6\frac{\theta^6}{6!}+i^7\frac{\theta^7}{7!}+\cdots \\
 &= 1+i\theta-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}-i\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+i\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\frac{\theta^6}{6!}-i\frac{\theta^7}{7!}+\cdots \\
 &= \left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\frac{\theta^6}{6!} + \cdots\right) 
    +i\left(\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\frac{\theta^7}{7!} \cdots\right) \\
 &= \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).
\end{align}

At this point, you can plug $-\theta$ in for $\theta$ to get to
$$e^{-i\theta} = \cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta).$$

Comment: :is that because $\cos({-x})=\cos{x}$ and $\sin({-x})=-\sin{x}$.

Comment: You're missing an $i$ in your last equation.

Comment: @justin I think it's more because $(-\theta)^{2n}=\theta^{2n}$ and $(-\theta)^{2n+1}=-\theta^{2n+1}$.

Comment: @Axoren Thanks! I'm surprised (if) that's all I missed.

Comment: @Mark McClure:could you explain the relation of $(\theta^{2n})$ with  $\cos\theta$ and  $\sin\theta$

Comment: @justin I guess I'm assuming that you know the power series expansions for sine and cosine. They are easily derived from Taylor's formula.